# DPAD events handling with Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, streaming, exoplayer

I am using ExoPlayer (Media3) in a streaming application, but DPAD events are not being handled. Touch events work properly but DPAD events don't work except the back button.

I am using the view like below:

```kotlin
    Box(modifier = modifier) {
        DisposableEffect(Unit) { onDispose { exoPlayer.release() } }

        AndroidView(
            factory = {
                PlayerView(context).apply {
                    player = exoPlayer
                    setShowPreviousButton(false)
                    setShowNextButton(false)
                    setShowSubtitleButton(false)
                    setShowFastForwardButton(false)
                    setShowRewindButton(false)
                    setShowBuffering(SHOW_BUFFERING_WHEN_PLAYING)

                    layoutParams =
                        FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams
                                .MATCH_PARENT,
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams
                                .MATCH_PARENT
                        )
                }
            }
        )
    }
```

Does anyone have any idea how can I properly handle those events? The controller doesn't show up on top of the video due to this and can't perform any events such as pause / play, etc.

Comment: What is the parent of Box Composable? Is it Surface?

Comment: It's not a surface, just a Scaffold Composable with a Box which has an Android View since there's no ExoPlayer for Compose directly.

Comment: I hope you are using tv.material3 components, if not, import tv compose dependencies and import all widgets from tv compose

Answer (score 1):

You need to listen the DPAD key events, and map the expected behaviour (Play, Pause, SeekBack, SeekForward, Back handling) to those events , and also update the PlayerView controller state according to the DPAD events, like showing or hiding the controller, My Scaffold() only consist this AndroidView, so the DPAD events are working well, didn't test it with more composables inside the Scaffold.

```
var shouldShowController by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
AndroidView(
        factory = { context ->
            PlayerView(context).also {
                it.player = exoplayer                             
            }
        },
        update = {

            if (shouldShowController) it.showController()
            else it.hideController()

        },
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(padding)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .aspectRatio(16 / 9f)
            .onKeyEvent { keyEvent ->

                if (keyEvent.nativeKeyEvent.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    when (keyEvent.nativeKeyEvent.keyCode) {
                        KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN -> {
                            shouldShowController = false
                            true
                        }

                        KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP -> {
                            shouldShowController = true
                            true
                        }

                        KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT -> {
                            shouldShowController = true
                            exoplayer.seekBack()
                            true
                        }

                        KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BUTTON_SELECT -> {
                            Log.d("PlayerScreen", "This is Select")
                            true
                        }

                        KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT -> {
                            shouldShowController = true
                            exoplayer.seekForward()
                            true
                        }

                        KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK -> {
                            navController.popBackStack()
                            true
                        }

                        KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER -> {

                            // if controller is visible then hide it else show it
                            shouldShowController = shouldShowController.not()
                            Log.d("PlayerScreen", "This is Center")
                            when {
                                exoplayer.isPlaying -> {
                                    // pause the video
                                    shouldShowController = true
                                    exoplayer.pause()
                                }

                               exoplayer.isPlaying.not() &&
                                        (playbackState == STATE_ENDED) -> {
                                    // play the video again
                                    exoplayer.seekTo(0)
                                    exoplayer.playWhenReady = true
                                }

                                else -> {
                                    // play the video
                                    shouldShowController = false
                                    exoplayer.play()
                                }
                            }
                            true
                        }

                        else -> {
                            false
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    true
                }
            }
    )
```